# How to tidy up/improve my question after I got the solution

Tags: discussion, editing, asking-questions

I recently asked [a question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/301769/64454) that was - long story short - answered by:

> There is an <strike>app'</strike> package for that!

This package indeed fully addresses my needs, but I was not aware of it (even after web search). In my question, I am thus showing my effort to develop this functionality (since I didn't succeed in finding the package by myself, so assuming it didn't exist). I explore various ways to solve my issue: some are successful but partial, some are unwieldy, and some are plain cul-de-sac.
So I think this question (and my attempts/partial solutions) still has some value for future user, who want - as I was - to use environments developed in the `tufte` class without using this class, and without knowing the existence of the `sidenote` package. However, expressed as it is now, this trials are "noise" between a simple and clear question, and its simple and clear answer.

**General question:** Once one got an answer to his/her question, what should be trimmed in the original post in order to make it as valuable as possible for future users?
*(That means in my particular case: what should I trim in my original post -- that is, I admit, a bit dense -- in order to make it valuable?)*

E.g., Should I remove all the work I did (trying to replicate `tufte` functionality) showing my efforts in my MWE, but that is now useless? It would make the question cleaner, but will lose content and potential "entry points" for people having same issue I had. 
Or should I post it as an answer (so that this work is not lost) but with a disclaimer saying that it's for archive only (and that DG' gave the satisfactory answer)?

Comment: you've clearly put a lot of work into the question, never mind the problem.  (and it's a happy resolution that there's a package that will work for you.)  it would really be a shame to simply wipe out all the information now in the question.  much can be learned from "mistakes" and running down blind alleys.  i'd be inclined to put a clear update notice *above the "edit 1"* portion saying that the question is solved by the accepted answer, but you've left earlier material hoping it will keep someone else from following those paths.

Comment: I updated my question according to Barbara's suggestions. (So this post originally referred to version #10 of my question). // I also updated this post in order to make it more general. // @barbarabeeton: you got it: since I worked quite a bit on this issue, I somehow didn't wanted that all this work just vanishes - i.e. I didn't wanted to accept I worked kind of for nothing!

Comment: I did this in my question. I  dont know, if I did this in a good way, but it is a starting point.
[http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300444/bulk-letter-loop-doesnt-work-read-to-doesnt-work]
The `former code` can be seen in the edit history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others go through the same process as you and therefore may use the same search path or approaches you did. So, if the attempts/code you present may provide value to the community or future visitors, then leave the post as-is.

One may, in general, present your question in a **TL;DR** and **Attempts** order, where the start of the question provides the core inquiry (that is, the post is **T**oo **L**ong and some people **D**on't want to **R**ead the entire thing), followed by your **Attempts**.